# Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server Xlib: Maximum number of clients reached xterm Xt error:

Tags: xterm

My requirement is to open around 700 xterms  but I get following error after 483 xterms:

***Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server Xlib: Maximum number of clients reached xterm Xt error: Can't open display: :0.0***

Please let me know how increase this limit.

I am using CentOS5.6 and using perl for this script.

Comment: Pardon my inquisitiveness, but what real-world problem could possibly require 700 open windows in a GUI? Perhaps we could come up with a different solution if you updated your question to include more information about the actual problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: MY requirement is to start multiple process on multiple logins of different machines available in my network, And I need to run the processes in xterm.

Comment: If they don't all need to run in a separate xterm window, things will be easier both to script and to control.  If you can run each in a separate `screen` instead, things will at least be detached from the Xlib limitations you are bumping into now.  But again, please describe what actual problem you are trying to solve in more detail, and we will surely be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. What we do is basically we start a daemon sort of stuff which opens up multiple xterms whose counts are based on inputs provided. Then ssh is issued on each xterm and a process is carried out on remote machine and when it completes the execution, it transfers the data back to the host machine and terminates the xterm.

Comment: None of this sounds like the actual xterm window is really necessary, unless you need manual user interaction in each window or something like that. What prevents you from running just `ssh` instead of `xterm -e ssh`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Perl has nothing to do with your problem.

I've heard that the number of clients is hard coded and this message suggests that you have reached it. So you probably can't increase it in Linux (sidenote: it seems that in Solaris [you can](http://www.science.uva.nl/pub/solaris/solaris2.html#q3.61)).

But you can probably make some room by killing some other clients. Use `xlsclients` to list them, stop the unnecessary ones, and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks...Would surely try this.